# Use PTRACE_GET_THREAD_AREA for a given tid

Tags: c, linux, x86, ptrace, thread-local-storage

For a debugging tool, I want to use ptrace to get the thread local storage (TLS) area for a given thread (given `tid_t tid`) 
(on x86_32).

The Linux manual says it requires the index into the `GDT`. How would I find a thread's GDT index?

Quote from the manual:

> PTRACE_GET_THREAD_AREA (since Linux 2.6.0)
>                 This operation performs a similar task to get_thread_area(2).
>                 It reads the TLS entry in the GDT whose index is given in
>                 addr, placing a copy of the entry into the struct user_desc
>                 pointed to by data.

Comment: Random guess, maybe use the value of the `fs` register?  Or `gs` in 32-bit code.  Maybe right-shifted by 2 because the low 2 bits of x86 segment selectors are privilege-level bits.  IDK if you can count on the segment register values selecting the right GDT entry or not, but that might be something to google on.